# to find the cross enthropy with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, cross-entropy

```
predicted_scores = tf.constant([
    [0.32,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5],
    [0.31,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5],
    [0.31,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5],
    [0.3111,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5],
    [0.33423,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5],
    [0.33243,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5],
    [0.334,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5],
    [0.32,0.2,0.15,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5]
])# predicted_scores(N, 8 , n_classes)

true_classes = tf.constant([
    [ 5,  5,  0, 10,  0,  0, 10,  5]
    
])
```

If I have predicted_scores and true_classes like this 
with torch I used

```
conf_loss_all = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(predicted_scores.view(-1, n_classes), true_classes.view(-1))  # (N * 8732)
```

to find the cross_enthropy
How should I find the cross entropy with TensorFlow?

Comment: Do not spam tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SparseCategoricalCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) loss.

```
scce = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
scce(true_classes[0], predicted_scores)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.8711867>
```